# Maximal interval of existence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a few functions which i have got from solving differential equations, and i am a bit confused about the maximal interval of existence and how to find it. Please could someone tell me if i have it right or not?

For $x(t) = \ln t $

I have Interval $I = (0,infty)$

For $x(t) = t\ln t - t + 1$

I have Interval $I = (-\infty, 1)$

For $x(t) = -\dfrac{3}{t^3 -1}$

I have Interval $I = (-6,6)$

Could someone please tell me if these are correct and if not, which is a good way of finding it without drawing the graph? Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: This depends on the the differential equations you started from. You might want to mention them. But for sure your second one is wrong as $\ln t$ is not defined for negative values. And the third one too, since $t=1$ is not in the domain.

Comment: okay so the first one started as x'=1/t, second as x' = ln t and third as x'=(x^2)(t^2).  I have changed the second interval to (0,1) is this correct?

Comment: For the first one. The ODE makes sense for $t\neq 0$. Note that if $x$ is a solution, it is differentiable with continuous derivative. On $(0,+\infty)$, we integrate and we find $x(t)-x(1)=\ln t$. On $(-\infty,0)$, we find $x(t)-x(-1)=\ln|t|$. Conversely, these are indeed solutions. So you have solved your ODE. The maximal interval depends on the initial condition. If it's for some $x_0>0$, then it is $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: the i.c for the first two are x(1)=0 and x(0)=1 for the third. So how do i go about getting the right answers? Im still massively confused as to if these are correct or not?!

Comment: If $x(1)=0$ for the first one, then $x(t)=\ln t$ on $(0,+\infty)$ and this is the maximal interval.

Comment: okay cool! Thanks. i can see that now when looking on the graph, so are the other 2 answers correct or wrong?!

Comment: here is a link to the second graph, could you please tell me how i work out the maximal interval? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=draw+graphs&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=graph+of+%28%28t%29%28ln+t%29-%28t%29%2B%281%29%29&oq=graph+of+%28%28t%29%28ln+t%29-%28t%29%2B%281%29%29&gs_l=serp.3...5465.8949.7.9416.11.11.0.0.0.1.101.932.10j1.11.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.GpFEaJTvOv8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=72b9c73243d0bb8d&biw=1366&bih=664